# How do I set a persistant time range on a metric in a Cloudwatch Dashboard using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Using the AWS console you can edit a metric and check a "Persist time range" box. This is documented as forcing "this widget to keep a defined time range independent of the global dashboard time range picker."

I think this feature would be helpful for gauge style metrics to show the current state of a metric while browsing a time range of other widgets.

Given a Cloudformation defined dashboard, how would I persist the time range of the first widget?

```
Resources:
  MyDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: MyDashboard
      DashboardBody:
        Fn::ToJsonString:
          widgets:
            - type: metric
              x: 0
              y: 0
              width: 4
              height: 6
              properties:
                view: gauge
                # Show the last 5 minutes despite the dashboard's time range
                # persistTime: true
                # period: 5m
                yAxis:
                  left:
                    min: 0
                    max: 100
                metrics:
                  -
                    - AWS/IoT
                    - MyThingsCount
                    - AggregationType
                    - count
                title: # of Things
                stat: Average
                region: !Ref AWS::Region
            - type: metric
              x: 4
              y: 0
              width: 6
              height: 6
              properties:
                metrics:
                  -
                    - AWS/IoT
                    - MyThingsCount
                    - AggregationType
                    - count
                title: Things over time
                stat: Average
                region: !Ref AWS::Region
```

Answer (score 0):

To set persisted time range on a widget we have to pass the `start` and `end` property in the widget model.

Here is the sample widget modal with persisted time range information:

- ##### YAMLS

```yaml
- type: metric
  properties:
      metrics:
      - - AWS/EC2
        - CPUUtilization
        - InstanceId
        - instance-ID
      period: 300
      stat: Average
      region: us-east-1
      start: -PT168H <--- Setting the start time of persisted timeragne
      end: P0D <--- Setting the end time of persisted timeragne
      title: With Persisted Time Range
```

- ##### JSON

```json
{
  "type": "metric",
  "properties": {
    "metrics": [
      [
        "AWS/EC2",
        "CPUUtilization",
        "InstanceId",
        "instance-ID"
      ]
    ],
    "period": 300,
    "stat": "Average",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "start": "-PT168H",
    "end": "P0D",
    "title": "With Persisted Time Range"
  }
}
```

I have tried the given sample `yaml` in the question, but it failed due to following error in the AWS CFN Designer:

```py
Template Error: Encountered unsupported function: Fn::ToJsonString 

Supported functions are: 
[Fn::AccountIdFromAlias, Fn::Base64, Fn::GetAtt, Fn::GetAZs, Fn::ImportValue, Fn::Join, Fn::Split, Fn::FindInMap, Fn::Select, Ref, Fn::Equals, Fn::If, Fn::Not, Condition, Fn::And, Fn::Or, Fn::Contains, Fn::EachMemberEquals, Fn::EachMemberIn, Fn::ValueOf, Fn::ValueOfAll, Fn::RefAll, Fn::Sub, Fn::Cidr]
```

I have tried the by manually passing the `JSON` string to the `DashboardBody` with `start` and `end` property worked fine. Here is the sample `yaml` I have used:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  CWD2BNQT:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard'
    Properties:
        DashboardName: CFN-Dashbaord-With-PTRW
        DashboardBody: "{\"widgets\":[{\"type\":\"metric\",\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"instance-ID\"]],\"period\":300,\"stat\":\"Average\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"start\":\"-PT168H\",\"end\":\"P0D\",\"title\":\"With Persisted Time Range\"}},{\"type\":\"metric\",\"properties\":{\"metrics\":[[\"AWS/EC2\",\"CPUUtilization\",\"InstanceId\",\"instance-ID\"]],\"period\":300,\"stat\":\"Average\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"title\":\"With Dashboard Time\"}}]}"
```

#### References:

- [AWS CloudWatch Dashboard Structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudwatch-dashboard.html)
- [AWS CloudWatch Widget Persist Time Range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/change_dashboard_refresh_interval.html)